# density of a synset

Tags: data-mining, text-mining

I am reading the paper [Text Classification Using WordNet Hypernyms](http://aclweb.org/anthology/W98-0706). In it, the author gives the definition of synset density as the number of occurrences of a synset in the WordNet output divided by the number of words in the document.

What is the synset density representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to this site! Please, try to be more specific when asking questions. In my answer I address the specific part of your question. If you wish to update the second part of the question, making it more specific, I will expand my answer accordingly as much as I can.

The formula you're looking into is a common case of [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization), not unlike the way the classical notion of [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density) is calculated, following the formula *density is the mass over the volume*:

[image]

In our case the mass of a [synset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym_ring) is the count of its occurences, and the volume of its "container" is the total number of words.

One way to think of it is this: Naturally, we want to measure the occurences, so the [dividend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)) should be obvious. Probably it is the [divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)) (division by the total number of words) that perplexes you.

Consider what would have happened if we didn't do this division. Let's take two documents: a tweet and Tolstoy's [War and peace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_and_Peace). The number of characters in the first document roughly corresponds to the number of pages in the second. So intuitively it should be clear to everyone that the number of occurences of any synset would be magnitudes higher in the second documents. When we are talking of density, this is an undesired effect. The density shouldn't depend on the quantity. This is why you divide by the total volume.

Comment: I am confused at the divisor part. occurences correspond to what? is it the number of times the synset has appeared in the document or is it the number of times it has appeared in output to a word i.e if two words have same synset then the occurence of that synset will be 2

Comment: Number of occurences in document. To me your example at the end corresponds to the first option, so I am havinga difficulties understanding the second option.

Comment: The author defines the density as:"the number of occurences of a synset in the wordnet output divided by wordlength of document".What does he mean by in the wordnet output

Comment: You seem to be referring to the third pass (c) on the left column on page 47. My interpretation is that it refers to the output of the second pass (b). This is the "global list of all synonym and hypernym synsets", which is essentially a bag-of-synsets (a structure similar to [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) which does represent the number of occurences of synsets in the original text.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had been stuck on this point for quite a while. Made the code and works perfectly. Previously was having acc of 35% but now i'm getting 95%

Comment: @samiullahilyas If you are happy with the answer, please indicate accordingly by either accepting it, or upvoting it, or both.

Comment: @mapto, if the question is not clear, and you think you understand what is being asked, feel free to edit the question make it clear.  Thanks.